# Uso de "casapuerta" fuera de Andalucía

Tags: uso-de-palabras, definiciones, sustantivos

Si hablamos de un edificio de viviendas o de una casa de vecinos, generalmente para referirnos a "pieza inmediata a la puerta de entrada que sirve de paso para acceder a las distintas viviendas" solemos usar la voz *[portal](https://dle.rae.es/?id=TjqJUpv)*. Para referirnos a este mismo concepto pero dentro de una vivienda, se puede usar esta misma voz, la latina *[atrio](https://dle.rae.es/?id=4L4kbeg)* o la árabe *[zaguán](https://dle.rae.es/?id=cHNOR45)*.

Sin embargo, existe otra palabra que también se puede aplicar a ambos conceptos y que yo, sevillano de toda la vida, no había oído en mi vida hasta que empecé a salir con una chica de la provincia de Cádiz: *[casapuerta](https://dle.rae.es/?id=7m99bNS)*.

El caso es que resulta que hasta ahora yo pensaba que *casapuerta* era una palabra usada solo en la zona de la bahía de Cádiz, y de hecho el *Vocabulario andaluz* de Alcalá Venceslada (1933) la define como "voz de la provincia de Cádiz".

Pero resulta que no siempre fue así. Buscando en el CORDE encuentro el siguiente texto:

> *En el portal de la calle, que en Sevilla llaman casapuerta, hizo una caballeriza para una mula [...].*
>
> Miguel de Cervantes Saavedra, "El celoso extremeño [Novelas ejemplares]", 1613 (España).

Genial, resulta que en mi propia tierra se usaba comúnmente esa palabra. De hecho el *Autoridades* (1729) dice:

> Es voz usada en Andalucía y otras partes.

Esta indicación se mantuvo en el diccionario hasta 1869, eliminándose en ediciones posteriores. Pero lo que me intriga es que no se mantuvo la indicación *And.* que hoy día se añade a las definiciones cuando estas solo aplican en Andalucía. Parecería que la palabra, en vez de ser cada vez menos usada hasta el punto de usarse solo en Cádiz, extendió su uso más allá de Despeñaperros.

¿Es así? ¿Se usa (o siquiera entiende) la voz *casapuerta* fuera de Andalucía? ¿O Venceslada tiene razón y hoy día solo se usa en la provincia de Cádiz?

Como curiosidad, el uso más antiguo registrado de la palabra es de aproximadamente 1580, en las *Novelas en verso* de Cristóbal de Tamariz, que era sevillano:

> *Apenas se sentó el galán pulido
>
>   quando se siente allá en la casapuerta
>
>   gran gente de a caballo y gran rüydo
>
>   como que llegan a la segunda puerta.
>
>   "¡Ay", le dice la dama, "mi marido
>
>   es que viene de cava, yo soy muerta!
>
>   ¡Ay triste, que no siento qué hagamos
>
>   ni sé de qué manera os escondamos!*

Y más curiosidad aún, todos los casos de *casapuerta* encontrados en el CREA (textos de entre 1979 y 1995) son de Fernando Quiñones, de Chiclana de la Frontera; José Manuel Caballero Bonald, de Jerez de la Frontera; y Eduardo Mendicutti, de Sanlúcar de Barrameda. Todos de pueblos de los alrededores de la bahía de Cádiz.

Comment: En la vida he oído *casapuerta*.

Comment: @walen Cervantes estuvo bastante tiempo viviendo en Sevilla (incluyendo su paso por la cárcel), no creo que cometiera ese error. Además cito otra obra de un sevillano que también usa la palabra.

Comment: @walen de hecho en el prólogo del Quijote el propio Cervantes dice que durante su estancia en la cárcel fue cuando tuvo la idea que engendró el libro. Y para atestiguarlo aquí en la calle Sierpes hay [una placa colocada](http://esasevilla.blogspot.com/2010/03/miguel-de-cervantes.html) donde se menciona ese dato.